# IE9 iFrame Ignores js files

Tags: javascript, iframe, internet-explorer-9

I have a very strange problem with IE9 and an iFrame I've implemanted inside an aspx page

the iFrame is connected to a login page of a different website and when i try to log in with username and password, the login page that supposed to call several js methods on external js files, well, doesn't call them

naturally, I've checked this page in FF and Chrome and it works perfectly but IE9 (and IE9 with competability mode) cant seems to "see" these js files

I opened IE tools (F12) and looked in the "script" tab, the external script weren't there
I've tried to link the scripts in my aspx file and it didn't help either

so what do you say
why is IE9 can't use js files inside an iFrame

Comment: Check the "Network" tab in the IE Dev Tools and click "Start Capture" -  what is the status of the external script after you reload?

Comment: all of the js files get the code 304, i wonder what 304 got to do with that? FF ofcourse returns with the code 200 to these files

Comment: 304 means *Not Modified* or in other words, it's taken from the browser cache. So that's not the problem.